# Calling a function from another script when clicking a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have Modal box popin with some text wrapped in a function. This modal is displayed when you click on a div.

Now I want to add a separate script with a div and when you click this div I want it to call the modal function and display that same modal popin.

Can anyone help me?

Here is the modal code:

```js
function modalpopin() {
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
  btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<div id="myBtn">Open Modal</div>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

This is the second script I tried. I want this to open the same modal popin. It does not seem to work...

```js
$("#modal-popin").click(function() {
  modalpopin();
});
```

```html
<div id="modal-popin">Click Here to open the Modal</div>
```

[JsFiddle Link Here](https://jsfiddle.net/mk2jsvxg/)

Comment: Added a JsFiddle

Comment: This looks like JavaScript to me, not Java. Please fix the tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting DOM elements using `$("selector")` is jQuery syntax, a library that you do not seem to use (it's not included in the JSFiddle).

Use vanilla JS:

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  modalpopin();
});
```

edit: jQuery is actually in the JSFiddle, my bad

Comment: Tried it. The modal does not open when clicking the div with the text... https://jsfiddle.net/xdoqsfv9/3/

Comment: The issue isn't the click event. You have wrapped all events in a function that doesn't do anything but define events. Only after you called the function (clicking the div), you can use the events (and thus click the button to open the modal). You don't need the function at all—just define events: https://jsfiddle.net/1g8xzmo0/2/

Comment: Thank you! You are right. That function did not make any sense. This works!

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
$( "#modal-popin" ).on( "click", function( event ) {
     modalpopin();
 });
```

Comment: Hi. I tried but it does not work. Nothing happens when I click the div in the second script...

Comment: Added a JsFiddle to the question.

Comment: You are using jquery and have you used jquery cdn in your file